# Firestore filter data by month

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to filter a data collection by month. But it's giving me an error  `TypeError: _this._firestore.collection('Employee').orderByChild is not a function`. Below is my code and database structure

[image]

```
const month = 5
firestore.collection('Employee').orderByChild("month").equalTo(month).once('value',snapshot=>{
                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{
                var users = childSnapshot.key;
                })
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're showing is not valid Firestore syntax at all.  It looks like you're mixing up Firestore queries with Realtime Database queries.  There is no `orderByChild` on a Firestore query, but there is on Realtime Database queries.  On top of that, you have no field called "month" in the document you're showing here, so it's not clear at all what you're trying to do with this query.

If you're using Firestore, I strongly suggest you familiarize yourself with Firestore queries using the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).  Ignore any documentation about Realtime Database.

Comment: what is the equivalent syntax for firestore?

Comment: Please see the link to the documentation in the answer.

Comment: I've scanned thorough documentation and I only see where example .where('birthDate', '>', startDate). No filtering of date by month

Comment: If you want to filter by month. you're going to have to filter on a field that contains the month. If that field doesn't exist, you're going to have to create it.